# Generated assets for dynamic asset delivery

Tags: android, android-assets, android-app-bundle

[Dynamic Asset delivery documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery/build-native-java) describes how to create a module for app bundle with assets. Essentially, use 'com.android.asset-pack' plug-in and place asset files in `asset-pack-name/src/main/assets/your-asset-directories`.
But what if I need to copy my assets from the output of another module? How do I add this dependency on a specific task of a different module? I couldn't even find the source code of asset-pack plugin.

One workaround I'm thinking about is creating a usual at-install "feature module" where I can specify the usual Android task dependencies, but that seems more complicated.